# How to access the data from streaming query in "memory" table for subsequent batch queries?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Given a `writeStream` call:

```
val outDf = (sdf.writeStream
  .outputMode(outputMode)
  .format("memory")
  .queryName("MyInMemoryTable")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(interval))
  .start())
```

How can I run a `sql` against the `MyInMemoryTable` e.g.

```
  val df = spark.sql("""select Origin,Dest,Carrier,avg(DepDelay) avgDepDelay 
                from MyInMemoryTable group by 1,2,3""")
```

The documentation for `Spark Structured Streaming` says that batch and streaming queries can be intermixed but the above is not working:

```
'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'writeStream' can be called only 
   on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;
```

So how can the `InMemoryTable` be used in subsequent queries?

Comment: I lost since I don't see why you'd get the error _"'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;"_ The code snippets look fine.

Comment: What do you really want to do since memory data source is only for testing and pretty limited in features.

Comment: I follow-up the in-memory table with `spark.sql("select * from MyInMemoryTable")` and write to parquet or kafka or what have you. From my answer below it is now working well: what I had missed is doing the `writeStream` in a loop. That was never documented and found it in only one place online.

Comment: I'm asking about the error _"'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;"_ specifically. When do you get it?

Comment: The mix up was in how to get results materialized (even into memory) while not incorrectly straying into `batch` calls instead of `stream` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following post on `Hortonworks` site has an approach that seems promising  https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/181979/spark-structured-streaming-formatmemory-is-showing.html
Here is the sample `writeStream` - which is of the same form as my original question:

```
 StreamingQuery initDF = df.writeStream()
          .outputMode("append")
          .format("memory")
          .queryName("initDF")
          .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1000))
          .start();
sparkSession.sql("select * from initDF").show();

initDF.awaitTermination();
```

And here is the response:

> Okay,the way it works is :
>
> In simple terms,think that The main Thread of your code launches
>   another thread in which your streamingquery logic runs.
>
> meanwhile ,your maincode is blocking due to

```
  initDF.awaitTermination().

sparkSession.sql("select * from initDF").show() => This code run on the mainthread ,and it reaches there only for the first time.
```

> So update your code to :

```
StreamingQuery initDF = df.writeStream() .outputMode("append") .format("memory") .queryName("initDF") .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1000)) .start();

while(initDF.isActive){
Thread.sleep(10000)

sparkSession.sql("select * from initDF").show()

}
```

> Now the main thread of your code will be going through the loop over and over again and it queries the table.

Applying the suggestions to my code results in :

```
while(outDf.isActive) {
  Thread.sleep(30000)
  strmSql(s"select * from $table", doCnt = false, show = true, nRows = 200)
}
outDf.awaitTermination(1 * 20000)
```

[image]

**Update** This worked great: I am seeing updated results after each mini batch.